# How to take a question off "on hold"?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, reopen-closed

I wish to have the following question reopened:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265961/what-happens-to-the-c-mysqlconnectionstringbuilder-classs-default-constructor.

How can I do that? I was told it was a C# programming question but I wish to port from windows 7 to Ubuntu Linux 15.10. How can I make it fit the scope of the site better?

Answer (score 8):

Your question seems to have very little to do with Linux. It doesn't matter that you're developing on a Linux machine; the question is about how something in C# works. As explained in the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Stack Overflow has many more users with the C# expertise necessary to answer this question. If Stack Overflow isn't accepting your questions, see [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)